# Fget in smtp function

Tags: php

I want to read last line which is 250  from Ehlo command. Currently it reads the first line which has 250 . Here is the current code

```
fputs($socket, "EHLO server1.aa.com\r\n"); // ehlo command

$res = fgets($socket, 1024); // read output

if (substr(trim($res), 0, 3) != "250") {
```

Please help me modify the code

Answer (score 1):

The response you're expecting looks like

```
250-foo
250-bar
250 OK
```

the last line is marked by not having a `-` after the three-digit-code but a space.
=> read all lines that have a 3 digit code followed by something else than a space.

```
function fetch_esmtp_response($source) {
    $response = array();
    do
    {
        $s = fgets($source, 1024);
        $response[] = $s;
    }   while( strlen($s) > 3 && ' '!==$s[3]);
    return $response;
}

fputs($socket, "EHLO server1.aa.com\r\n"); // ehlo command
$response = fetch_esmtp_response($socket);
var_dump($response);
```

oh and btw: Unless this is purely for education purposes don't code this yourself but use a email library like e.g. [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `fgets()` (or anything) on a socket, it isn't guaranteed that you are going to get the amount of data specified.  What I think you should do is fetch all of the data into a string buffer, and parse that buffer until you find the data you need.